# Что произошло с подсветкой синтаксиса?

Tags: обсуждение, подсветка-синтаксиса, раньше-было-лучше

Что случилось со старой подсветкой синтаксиса? Что за ужасные цвета?

```
// c++
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}
```

```py
# python
def main():
    print("hello")
```

```js
// js
function main() {
    console.log("hello");
}
```

Comment: Литералы вообще слабо отличаются от скобочек и комментариев даже при полной яркости :(

Comment: Можно сделать немного поярче: .s-code-block { filter: saturate(1.25); }

Comment: Поменялся движок подсветки синтаксиса. [Goodbye, Prettify. Hello highlight.js! Swapping out our Syntax Highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) [How does the highlight.js change affect Stack Overflow specifically?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401031/how-does-the-highlight-js-change-affect-stack-overflow-specifically)

Comment: Надеюсь, никто не против метки [meta-tag:раньше-было-лучше] - по-моему вполне подходит вопросу)

Comment: @insolor хм, цвета поменяли похоже. Теперь комментарии и литералы заметно отличаются. Так что, как по мне, уже нормальные цвета, но метка пусть будет на усмотрение ТС

Comment: Цвета уже обсуждаются на англометах: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401521/673852), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354541/226705)

Answer (score 12):

Судя по тому, что цвета изменились и в старых сообщениях, просто поменяли стили.

---

1. Недавно писали, что поменялась утилита для маркдауна.
2. Может просто дизайн обновился.
3. А может подготовка к предстоящим изменениям.

PS: Жду таблицы.

| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| Cell 1   | Cell 2   |
| Cell 3   | Cell 4   |

PPS: А цвета действительно противные - блёклые какие-то.

Comment: "может подготовка к предстоящим изменениям" Ох... Лучше бы откатили года на два назад.

Comment: да норм цвета, что вам не нравится

Comment: @mymedia слишком однотонно и нет контраста. **Предыдущая стилизация синтаксиса была хотя-бы читаема.**